# Cocoa Drag and Drop delegates not working the way I would expect

Tags: xcode, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I made a very simple class that subclasses NSTextField so I could have more control over the drag and drop behavior, but I'm running into confusion. According to what I think I understand in the apple.developer docs on Dragging destinations, I should be able to get the delegates to fire when I enter or exit the bounds of the text field, but what I get instead is that the delegates don't fire until I have dropped something into the textField and then I try to drag it out.

I have a MyController class which is an NSObject and I have a CustomFields class of type NSTextField;  There is nothing in the controller class.

Here is the code:

```
//  CustomFields.h
//  Drags
//

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Foundation/foundation.h>

@interface CustomFields : NSTextField{

    NSString *tempStorage_;
    unsigned long last_;
}
@property(readwrite, retain) NSString *tempStorage;

@end



//
//  CustomFields.m
//  Drags
//

#import "CustomFields.h"

@implementation CustomFields

@synthesize tempStorage = tempStorage_;


- (id)init{

    if (self) {

        self = [super init];

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{

    [self.tempStorage release ];
    [super release];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{

    NSLog(@"Awake from nib called");

    self.tempStorage = @"";
    self->last_ = 0;
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSPasteboardTypeString ,   NSPasteboardTypeString, nil]];

    [super awakeFromNib];

 }



- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Inside dragging entered");

        return NSDragOperationCopy;
}



- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSLog(@" draggingUpdated called");
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}



- (void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Inside dragging exited");

}

@end


//
//  MyController.h
//  Drags
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class CustomFields;

@interface MyController : NSObject{

    IBOutlet NSButton *myButton_;

    IBOutlet CustomFields *field1_;
    IBOutlet CustomFields *field2_;

}

@end



//
//  MyController.m
//  Drags
//


#import "MyController.h"
#import "CustomFields.h"

@implementation MyController



@end
```

I made sure I assigned the correct class to the fields(CustomFields) in IB and connected them. As you can see, for the moment I would be happy to get log statements at the proper time. I also tried changing the MyController class to NSViewController and NSView so I could try registerForDraggedTypes there. That did'nt help anything and I don't think I should expect it to. I think the behaviors I want should be confined to the CustomFields Class which is one of the reasons the MyController class can be empty for the moment.

So any help is much apprecieted.

Comment: What about the default text field dragging behaviour are you trying to change?

Comment: well, for one thing, if there is already something in the box, and the user drags something else to the box, the first string should disappear, then if the user does not drop, the first string should re-appear. I do not think I can create that behavior without subclassing the textField(view)